# How to remove an edge attribute in python-igraph

Tags: python, python-3.x, igraph

I want to remove an edge attribute from a Graph object in `python-igraph`. The equivalent igraph R function is cleverly called [`delete_edge_attr`](https://igraph.org/r/doc/delete_edge_attr.html). I haven't been able to find an equivalent function/method in Python... is there one?

If not, is there another way to do it? (I tried a simple `g.es['edge_attr']= []` but this didn't work).

**Example Code**

```
g = ig.Graph.Tree(10, 2)        #Generate random graph
g_betweenness = g.betweenness() #Calculate betweenness for graph
g['betweenness'] = betweenness  #Assign betweenness as edge attribute
print(g.attributes())
g['betweenness'] = []           #Attempt to remove betweenness edge attribute (incorrect)
print(g.attributes())
```

**Output**

```
['betweenness']
['betweenness']
```

**Desired output**

```
['betweenness']
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be able to set it to an empty array, but your intuition about directly altering the `EdgeSequence` was already pretty good. You can simply delete the argument with Python's internal `del()`, I've included a minimal example below:

```
import igraph
# minimal graph
G = igraph.Graph()
G.add_vertices(2)
G.add_edge(0,1)

# add your property
G.es['betweenness'] = [1]

# print edge attribute (note the difference to your example)
print(G.es.attribute_names())
# output: ['weight']

# delete argument
del(G.es['weight'])

# print again
print(G.es.attribute_names())
# output: []
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I knew there had to be a simple solution